# Unable to verify a GitHub page to create a publisher in Pub.dev

Tags: flutter, dart, github, github-pages, pub.dev

Some time ago, I was able to verify my blog at blogspot.com, and published packages on Pub.dev under that publisher. Recently, I decided to switch to a GitHub page, as it is a lot better from the version control perspective as well as gives a lot more flexibility in content creation. However, I'm unable to verify my GitHub page: Pub.dev requires domain verification, and I'm lost in endless attempts to find the DNS configuration page where I could paste a TXT record issued by the Google Search Console. I also thought that there could be a file with a special name in the root directory of my GitHub site which is supposed to hold that info. But I didn't find anything like that.

Is this achievable at all? I don't want to associate another domain with my GitHub page, as this adds no value. I tried to point my blogspot.com page to the GitHub one but did not succeed either. Why is it made so hard to do the most obvious thing: to link a Pub.dev publisher to a GitHub page? Especially, given that the most repos are hosted by GitHub anyway. Or maybe this feature is available for the paid GitHub accounts only?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: The package home page or repository is independent from the domain you use for publisher verification.  Publisher verification is tied to your pub.dev account; it is not per-package.  You also don't have to be a verified publisher.

Comment: @jamesdlin, yes, I know packages and repositories are independent of publishers. My question though is different: how to create and verify a publisher of a very specific kind? I mentioned packages solely to explain my final goal. And yes, I still prefer my packages to appear under a verified publisher.

Comment: Ah, you mean a "GitHub Page" as a proper noun, as in a website hosted by GitHub under your own domain name, not just some page under github.com.    Why does it matter where your site is hosted?  The pub.dev publisher verification requires only that you own your own domain name.  Can't you set the TXT record through your domain registrar?

Comment: @jamesdlin, this is exactly the problem: I don't have a separate paid domain anywhere, and I can't find where to add the TXT record to the DNS configuration under username.blogspot.com (most likely, that is unavailable at all). I still prefer username.github.io to be shown as a publisher, as there is a website it points to under the publisher details. I want to keep everything simple and concise. I guess, it could be much easier to allow the URL prefix verification at Pub.dev. Or, upload some special file with the TXT record in it. But I suspect there is no such thing available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the best solution I came up with is to add

`<meta content='0; url=https://username.github.io/' http-equiv='refresh'/>`

to my Blogspot theme's HTML as well as replace the top (single) post's content with

```
<h2>
    <p>
        This blog has been moved to
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="https://username.github.io/">https://username.github.io/</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        Redirecting...
    </p>
</h2>
```

Not very elegant but allows me to avoid doubling the maintenance and to focus on the GitHub page. By verifying the GitHub Page's prefix URL in Google Search Console, I made that searchable.

However, on the Pub.dev side, it still shows publisher as *username.blogspot.com*, and when someone goes to the publisher details and click a similar link, they eventually get re-directed to the GitHub page. Better than nothing.

Comment: I ended up purchasing my own _.com_ domain. However, there was no special need to purchase an _SSL certificate_, as GitHub provides that with the free site. I was given that advice on Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Verified publishers on pub.dev require that you own your own domain name.  A subdomain will not suffice.

From https://pub.dev/create-publisher (sign-in required):

> The user account creating a publisher must be the verifier of the *domain property* – not just a verifier of a *URL prefix property* – or a collaborator on a property that someone else has verified.

Once you've paid for your own domain name, you should be able to set the TXT record through your domain registrar.

Comment: But I was able to verify the _username.blogspot.com_ which is a subdomain. Still, you might be right - I just wanted to ensure there is no workaround by chance.